# Push event not being triggered in Service worker

Tags: javascript, events, push-notification, service-worker

So I have managed to get push notifications to work. The problem is that whilst they appear on my screen, they don't seem to be triggering the push event in my serviceworker. I am trying to console.log something once the event is triggered but it's not working. Does anyone know what could be causing this problem? (Service worker is registered properly).

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (e) {
   console.log('hello world');
  if (!(self.Notification && self.Notification.permission === 
     'granted')) {
    //notifications aren't supported or permission not granted!
    return;
 }

if (e.data) {
    var msg = e.data.json();
    console.log(msg)
    e.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(msg.title, {
        body: msg.body,
        icon: msg.icon,
        actions: msg.actions
    }));
}
```

});

After writing this I discovered that the push event works correctly on my phone but not on my laptop.

Comment: can you add some code of what you've tried?

Comment: I added the code I have in the event listener. The console.logs in the code don't display even though the push notification displays on the screen.

Comment: I just discovered that the console.logs are working on my phone but not on my computer. Please let me know if you have any ideas.